# When I use JavaScript to update the src of an iframe, it's not updating fast and sometimes fails to update after a few clicks, what can I do?

Tags: iframe

```js
$('#button').click(()=>{
  $('iframe').attr('src', 'about:blank');
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'https://umbc.edu/?'+Math.random());
  },0)
  
})



$('#button2').click(()=>{
  $('iframe').attr('src', 'https://example.org?'+Math.random());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<button id='button'>UMBC</button>
<button id='button2'>Example</button>
</p>
<div>
<iframe width="600" height="300" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>
```

Click back and forth on the two buttons, you will see that the iframe is not updating gracefully and sometimes it doesn't reload at all.

What I expect is quite simple:

1. Click on a button, the iframe goes to `about:blank` (so the current page will be removed)
2. Then try the best to load the new target.

Is there anything mistake I have made?